# JNI fatal error when calling GetStringChars

Tags: java, crash, java-native-interface

I'm trying to write a native function for

```
protected static native boolean _connect(String user, String password,
                                         String machine) throws Exception;
```

The implementation goes like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_jniprint__1connect
(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, jstring _machine, jstring _user, jstring _pass)
{
cout << "Connecting !!!!!!!!" << endl;
const jchar *machine = env->GetStringChars(_machine, JNI_FALSE);    
cout << "after machine!!!!!!!!" << endl;
return JNI_FALSE;
}
```

It works perfectly when the _machine parameter is not null, when it is null - jvm crashes violently

```
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:  

  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d96019f, pid=16444, tid=10744  

 JRE version: 6.0_30-b12  
 Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )  
 Problematic frame:  
 V  [jvm.dll+0xa019f]
```

...

Whats going on?

Comment: What is the question here?  Are you asking why `GetStringChars` fails when you pass a null argument?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @EdwardThomson - I surely didn't expect the whole JRE to crash with a fatal error. Returning a null, or raising a some kind of exception would be more appropriate, IMHO.

Comment: I would expect it to `abort()`, actually.

Comment: abort() would mean it actually did a null check and in that case it could just as well have handled it. I am pretty sure it aborts when you run it with -Xcheck:jni though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you made sure you are not passing it null? 
**EDIT:** Sorry for reading sloppy, you ARE passing it null. In that case it SHOULD crash.

Also, you should call ReleaseStringchars() or future calls might crash (or give you other problems).

Edit: Running the jvm with -Xcheck:jni is often helpful when developing with JNI. Not sure it would help you here but I thought I should toss it in anyway.

Comment: Thanks, after some googling yesterday I have found the '-Xcheck:jni' parameter and it did lead me to the "null passed instead of a string" error. Why do you think it was designed to crash so violently?

Comment: @Vic well, I have coded quite a lot of JNI and that's just how it is. I've never really thought about "why" as it is how most C APIs behaves, null checking is typically not the responsibility of the callee but the caller in C.

Answer (score 0):

you set the string in java side equal to null. you must set that string equal to "".